# Facebook Ads gets rejected

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

I have a web shop, for sports wear. I have Facebook Page as well. But, whenever I try to advertise, for example, grid photo of few shoes, and recently just a link to a web site (web shop in Shopify), I get following error:

> Error message from Facebook: This ad isn't running because it promotes content that is against Advertising Policies.Our policies are in place to keep users safe and foster a positive global community. (https://www.facebook.com/policies/ads)

Does anyone have a clue what can be a problem?

I read those policies, and found nothing wrong.